# wordpress get posts random from specific categories

Tags: wordpress, random, categories

Need some help.
I have code in functions.php. when going to myweb.com/random=1 it goes to random post but I want it picks random only from chosen categories. I tried that but it still picks it from all categories.

```
add_action('init','random_add_rewrite');
function random_add_rewrite() {
    global $wp;
    $wp->add_query_var('random');
    add_rewrite_rule('random/?$', 'index.php?random=1', 'top');
}

add_action('template_redirect','random_template');
function random_template() {
    if (get_query_var('random') == 1) {
        $posts = get_posts('category=14,17,23,28,32&orderby=rand&numberposts=1');
        foreach($posts as $post) {
            $link = get_permalink($post);
        }
        wp_redirect($link,307);
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you try `setup_postdata($post)` at the beginning of your loop and see if it change anything?

Comment: no changes :/ but thanks for trying

Comment: What kind of posts are you trying to query, is that custom posts, and categories custom taxonomy categories?

Comment: posts which have atleast one of the category i have picked here. 
what i want is when someone clicks myweb.com/random=1 link he will get random post one of these categories. unfortunately any random posts plugins don't fit with my idea. because I need specific link for that so I can put it to menu

Comment: Well the reason I ask you this is because you need to do a taxonomy query if it's not the default categories system for default posts of WP. I'll write an answer with tax_query, see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try seeing if this revised one works

```
add_action('init','random_add_rewrite');
function random_add_rewrite() {
    global $wp;
    $wp->add_query_var('random');
    add_rewrite_rule('random/?$', 'index.php?random=1', 'top');
}

add_action('template_redirect','random_template');
function random_template() {
    if (get_query_var('random') == 1) {
        $arguments = array('orderby' => 'rand', 'numberposts' => 1, 'category' => '14,17,23,28,32');
        $posts = get_posts( $arguments );
        foreach($posts as $post) {
            $link = get_permalink($post);
        }
        wp_redirect($link,307);
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: `get_posts` pass the arguments through `WP_Query`, so you can pass a query string - array is not mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

If you query some custom posts, you'll need to do a taxonomy query instead of using `category` parameter - which refer to the default post type categories.

```
$args = array(
    'numberposts' => 1,
    'orderby'=> 'rand',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category', 
            'field' => 'term_id', 
            'terms' => array(14,17,23,28,32)
        )
    )
);
$posts = get_post($args);
```